# Issue when trying to run c program in terminal

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, terminal

So I am having an issue running a c program in terminal window. I am running on Linux Mint and attempting to compile and run the program in the terminal window. I have 3 files: the main file (cShell.c), the commands file (commands.c), and the header file for the commands file (commands.h).

They are listed below. All three files are located in the same folder, which is the working directory in terminal when I attempt to run. I can successfully compile the program using the following syntax -

```
gcc *.c -o a.out
```

However when I attempt to run the actual file using "./cShell" I get the following errors:

```
student@4720-devel ~/Desktop/cShell $ ./cShell.c
./cShell.c: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./cShell.c: line 8: `void print_user(void)'
student@4720-devel ~/Desktop/cShell $
```

cShell:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "commands.h"



void print_user(void)
{
    char user[1024];
    if (getlogin_r(user, sizeof(user)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "User not found");
    }
    else {
    strcpy(user, getlogin());
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", user);
    }
}


void print_cwd(void)
{
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "CWD not found");
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", cwd);
}

#define RL_BUFSIZE 1024
char *read_line(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  ssize_t bufsize = 0; // have getline allocate a buffer for us
  getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
  return line;
}


#define TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
char **split_line(char *line)
{
  int bufsize = TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  char *token;

  if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  token = strtok(line, TOK_DELIM);
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += TOK_BUFSIZE;
      tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tokens) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}

int launch(char **args)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;


//  if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
//    perror("lsh");
//  }
//  return 1;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (pid < 0) {
    // Error forking
    perror("lsh");
  } else {
    // Parent process
    do {
      waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}

int execute(char **args)
{
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL) {
    // An empty command was entered.
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < num_builtins(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }

  return launch(args);
}

void loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
    print_user();
    printf("@");
    print_cwd();
    printf("> ");
    line = read_line();
    args = split_line(line);
    status = execute(args);

    free(line);
    free(args);
  } while (status);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Load config files, if any.

  // Run command loop.
  loop();

  // Perform any shutdown/cleanup.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

commands.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) ;

/*
    get current user????!?!?
    o         ls
    o         stat
    o         timeout
    ·         grep
    ·         diff

x         clear
x         cat
x         cp
x         cd
x         mkdir
x         rmdir
x         sleep
x         kill
x         env
x         wait
 */

struct stat
{
    dev_t   st_dev;         /* inode's device */
    ino_t   st_ino;         /* inode's number */
    mode_t  st_mode;        /* inode protection mode */
    nlink_t st_nlink;       /* number of hard links */
    uid_t   st_uid;         /* user ID of the file's owner */
    gid_t   st_gid;         /* group ID of the file's group */
    dev_t   st_rdev;        /* device type */
    off_t       st_size;        /* file size, in bytes */
    time_t  st_atime;       /* time of last access */
    long        st_spare1;
    time_t  st_mtime;       /* time of last data modification */
    long        st_spare2;
    time_t  st_ctime;       /* time of last file status change */
    long        st_spare3;
    long        st_blksize;     /* optimal blocksize for I/O */
    long        st_blocks;      /* blocks allocated for file */
    u_long  st_flags;       /* user defined flags for file */
    u_long  st_gen;         /* file generation number */
};

struct dirent {
    unsigned long   d_fileno;   /* file number of entry */
    unsigned short  d_reclen;   /* length of this record */
    unsigned char   d_type;     /* file type, see below */
    unsigned char   d_namlen;   /* length of string in d_name */
    char                        d_name[255 + 1];    /* name must be no longer than this */
};

typedef struct DIR {
    char          *dirname;                    /* directory being scanned */
    struct dirent        current;                     /* current entry */
    int           dirent_filled;               /* is current un-processed? */
} DIR;

char *builtin_str[] = {
        "cd",
        "ls",
        "help",
        "exit",
        "mkdir",
        "rmdir",
        "stat",
        "cp",
        "cat",
        "clear",
        "sleep",
        "kill",
        "wait",
        "timeout",
        "env"

};

int num_builtins(void) {
    return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}

int _diff(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL || args[2] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected 2 arguments to \"diff,\"\n");
    } else {
        wait(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

extern char **environ;
int _env(char **args)
{
    for (char **env = environ; *env; ++env)
        printf("%s\n", *env);
    return 1;
}

#define ESRCH 3
//ESRCH process does not exist
int _timeout(char **args)
{
    int exitstatus;
    if (args[1] == NULL || args[2] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected 2+ arguments to \"timeout,\" duration, command, args[]\n");
    } else {
        int numArgs;
        numArgs = sizeof(args)/sizeof(char*);
        char* newArgs;
        newArgs = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(numArgs-2));

        for (int i = 2; i < numArgs; i++){
            newArgs[i-2] = args[i];
        }

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            // Child process
          for (int i = 0; i < num_builtins(); i++) {
            if (strcmp(newArgs[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
              return (*builtin_func[i])(newArgs);
            }
          }

            if (execvp(newArgs[0], newArgs) == -1) {
                perror("lsh");
            }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid < 0) {
            // Error forking
            perror("lsh");
        } else {
            // Parent process
            int duration;
            duration = atoi(args[1]);
            do {
                wait(1);
                duration -= 1;
            } while (duration > 0 && kill(pid, 0) != ESRCH);
            if (duration == 0  && kill(pid, 0) == ESRCH){
                kill(pid, 7);
                fprintf(stdout, "Timeout exceeded; Child pid %d killed.\n", pid);
            }
            else{
                fprintf(stdout, "Child pid %d completed in %d seconds..\n", pid, atoi(args[1])-duration);
            }
        }
        free(newArgs);
    }
    return 1;
}

int _wait(char **args)
{
    int exitstatus;
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"wait\"\n");
    } else {
        exitstatus = wait(atoi(args[1]));
        fprintf(stdout, "Child process exit status: %d\n", exitstatus);
    }
    return 1;
}

int _kill(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL || args[2] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected 2 arguments to \"kill\" - pid, signum\n");
    } else {
        if (kill(atoi(args[1]),atoi(args[2])) != 0) {
            perror("Error");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int _sleep(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"sleep\"\n");
    } else {
        if (sleep(atoi(args[1])) != 0) {
            perror("Error");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

//doesn't work in debug; works in real term
int  _clear(char **args)
{
    const char *CLEAR_SCREEN_ANSI = "\e[1;1H\e[2J";
    write(fileno(stdout), CLEAR_SCREEN_ANSI, 12);
    return 1;
}

int _cat(char **args)
{
    FILE *read_this;
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"cat\"\n");
    } else {
        read_this = fopen(args[1], "r");
        if (read_this == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        while(NULL != fgets(buf, sizeof buf, read_this)) {
            printf("%s", buf);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


#define O_RDONLY    0x0000      /* open for reading only */
#define O_WRONLY    0x0001      /* open for writing only */
#define O_RDWR      0x0002      /* open for reading and writing */
#define O_ACCMODE   0x0003      /* mask for above modes */
#define O_CREAT     0x0200      /* create if nonexistant */
#define O_TRUNC     0x0400      /* truncate to zero length */
#define O_EXCL      0x0800      /* error if already exists */
#define EINTR       4       /* Interrupted system call */

char *strcpy(char *d, const char *s)
{
    char *saved = d;
    while (*s)
    {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }
    *d = 0;
    return saved;
}

int _cp(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL || args[2] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected 2 arguments to \"cp\"\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char* to;
    char* from;
    to = malloc(sizeof(args[2]));
    from = malloc(sizeof(args[1]));
    strcpy(to, args[2]);
    strcpy(from, args[1]);

    int errno;
    int fd_to, fd_from;
    char buf[4096];
    ssize_t nread;
    int saved_errno;

    fd_from = open(from, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_from < 0)
        return -1;

    fd_to = fopen(to, "rb+");
    if( fd_to == NULL) {
        fd_to = fopen(to, "wb");
    }

    fd_to = open(to, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    if (fd_to < 0)
        goto out_error;

    while (nread = read(fd_from, buf, sizeof buf), nread > 0)
    {
        char *out_ptr = buf;
        ssize_t nwritten;

        do {
            nwritten = write(fd_to, out_ptr, nread);
            if (nwritten >= 0)
            {
                nread -= nwritten;
                out_ptr += nwritten;
            }
            else if (errno != EINTR)
            {
                goto out_error;
            }
        } while (nread > 0);
    }

    if (nread == 0)
    {
        if (close(fd_to) < 0)
        {
            fd_to = -1;
            goto out_error;
        }
        close(fd_from);
        free(to);
        free(from);
        /* Success! */
        return 1;
    }
    out_error:
    saved_errno = errno;
    close(fd_from);
    if (fd_to >= 0)
        close(fd_to);
    free(to);
    free(from);
    errno = saved_errno;
    perror("Error: ");
    return 1;
}

//fixme
int _stat(char **args)
{
    struct stat *buf;
    buf = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"stat\"\n");
    }
    else {
        if (stat(args[1], buf) != 0) {
            perror("Error: ");
        }
        else {
            long size = buf->st_blocks;
            fprintf(stdout, "%lu", size);
        }
    }
    //free(buf);
    return 1;
}

//fixme
int _ls(char **args)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    char cwd[1024];
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        dp = opendir (cwd);
        if (dp != NULL)
        {
            while (ep = readdir (dp))
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ep->d_name);
            (void) closedir (dp);
        }
        else
            perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
    }
    else {
        dp = opendir (args[1]);
        if (dp != NULL)
        {
            while (ep = readdir (dp))
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", ep->d_name);
            (void) closedir (dp);
        }
        else
            perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n");
    return 1;
}

int _rmdir(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"rmdir\"\n");
    } else {
        if (rmdir(args[1]) != 0) {
            perror("Error: ");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int _mkdir(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument to \"mkdir\"\n");
    } else {
        if (mkdir(args[1]) != 0) {
            perror("Error");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int _cd(char **args)
{
    if (args[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
    } else {
        if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
            perror("Error");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int _help(char **args)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_builtins(); i++) {
        printf("  %s\n", builtin_str[i]);
    }
    printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");
    return 1;
}

int _exit(char **args)
{
    return 0;
}

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
        &_cd,
        &_ls,
        &_help,
        &_exit,
        &_mkdir,
        &_rmdir,
        &_stat,
        &_cp,
        &_cat,
        &_clear,
        &_sleep,
        &_kill,
        &_wait,
        &_timeout,
        &_env,
};
```

commands.h:

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_H_
#define COMMANDS_H_

int cd(char **args);
int ls(char **args);
int help(char **args);
int shell_exit(char **args);
int num_builtins(void);

char *builtin_str[];
int (*builtin_func[]) (char **);

#endif /* COMMANDS_H_ */
```

Am I compiling or running the program wrong? Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You see `-o a.out`? Try to run `./a.out`

Comment: `cShell.c` is a source file. You don't execute it, you execute the compilation output.

Comment: As for your error when trying to run `./cShell`: I suspect it's trying to execute it as a script file, which it is not.

Comment: "*run the actual file using `./cShell`"*": Didn't you mean to write: "*... using `./cShell.c`*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"gcc *.c -o a.out". However when I attempt to run the actual file using "./cShell"`

`-o a.out` says to write the output of the compile to a file called `a.out` (which is the default anyway, so you could leave it out).

But then you try to run `./cShell.c` (or `./cShell` - your question says both in different parts)? You've just compiled cShell.c - so now you want to execute it (and not the compiled version) ? That's not how it works.

Try `gcc *.c -o cShell` then `./cShell` (note, not cShell.c)

Comment: This was it thanks for your answer! Coming from a Python background these kind of things confuse me. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with

```
gcc MyProgram.c -o MyProgram
```

And then

```
./MyProgram
```

Make sure you have sufficient rights to the source file and the out file. Check that with

```
ls -la
```

You suppose to see something like this for the source file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user < stuff you dont need now > MyProgram.c
```

and something like this for the output file of your compilation:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user < stuff you dont need now > MyProgram*
                                                   this star means 
                                               this file is executable
```

If you don't, use chmod to change the rights. `chmod` has the following syntax (of course there is a man page)

```
chmod 0775 MyProgram
```

where 0 defines an octal represantation input, and the rest numbers refer to `user` `group` `other`. Given the fact you are the current user trying to run `MyProgram` you can simply rely to `chmod 0744 MyProgram` to execute it ('./MyProgram' given the fact that you are inside the file that it exists).

You can find more of `chmod` online and the man page.

Comment: "*`chmod 0777 programmname.c ....`*" no, no, just no. Do not flag a source file as executable, which it simply isn't! Doing so leads to exactly such confusion the OP is facing. :-(

Comment: OP didn't state the exact nature of his problem. And i ofc gave him a general blueprint to search his way through, since there is no precise program names and stuff. 
Never the less, i will update my post to fit those needs cause you are right about +x in chmod! Thanks for pointing out!